# Suggest some site for "Roles of inbuilt Interceptors."

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts2, interceptor

I have looked up for interceptors in struts2 at many places. All the great tutorials and links explain the meaning of interceptors and how they work.

But as I understand, the real power of interceptors is in understanding the roles of inbuilt interceptors in struts2-core library.

As an example so far I have understood that `params` is the interceptor which sets the value of `HttpServletRequest` parameters into the `Action` class variables.

I tried to de-compile the interceptor class files from jar but those codes are complex. I can't understand it.

I want to learn roles of those inbuilt interceptors as many as possible. Please suggest a link.

Comment: Struts 2 In Action explains all those... Also struts 2 is an apache project no need to decompile the source code. You can simply get the original source code itself...

Comment: Yea, I can get the code from it. But the point is that it's too complex to understand. I don't want to give it so much time. I just need to know it's role, not detailed functionality.

Anyways, can you give me the link for Struts2 In Action?

Comment: Why would you decompile the class files when the source is trivially available? What's wrong with the documentation of each interceptor, available on the Struts 2 wiki? S2 in Action is a book: the link is called "Amazon" or the Manning site.

Comment: Okay...I got it. I didn't realize from the first comment that Struts2 In Action was a book. I already looked it up and figured that out. Even purchased it too.

Thanx for the help anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to learn roles of those inbuilt interceptors as many as possible.

The role of each Interceptor [is explained in the related page](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/interceptors.html#Interceptors-FrameworkInterceptors), as pointed out by @AnkurLathi (I've linked 2.3.x version, it should always be better, even if the documentation doesn't change);

> I tried to de-compile the interceptor class files from jar but those codes are complex. I can't understand it.

You don't need to decompile anything. There are sites like ***grepCode*** or ***Jarvana*** that helps you providing the source code of most of the libraries out there; but for Struts2, simply refer to the [official source code repository](http://struts.apache.org/dev/builds.html);

[Here is the direct link to the Interceptor source code path.](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/struts/struts2/trunk/core/src/main/java/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/)

Note that some Interceptors are placed in other paths, because they're still packaged as XWork stuff.

Comment: Thanx a lot Andrea Ligios, your answer was really genuine and a lot helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to know the role of each Struts 2 interceptor then you should visit it's Documentation at:

http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/interceptors.html#Interceptors-FrameworkInterceptors

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be helpful for yout

[Interceptor Interface in Struts 2.2.1](http://www.roseindia.net/struts/struts/struts2.2.1/InterceptorInterface.html)

[Role of interceptor](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/interceptors.html) Look into the framework section and you will be able to get your answer